# Suppose that $f$ on $[0,1]$ satisfies $f(\int_0^1 g dx) \leq \int_0^1 f(g(x)) dx$. Then $f$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f$ satisfies $f(\int_0^1 g(x) dx) \leq \int_0^1 f(g(x)) dx$. Whenever $g$ is bounded and measurable. Then $f$ is convex.

Any hints are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, bad typo. $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$.

Comment: Hint: Consider $g$ as a suitable step function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $s,t \in \mathbb R$ and $\lambda  \in [0,1]$. Let $g(x) = s,$ for $x < \lambda$ and $g(x) = t$ for $x \ge \lambda$. Then $$\int_0^1 g(x) dx = \int_0^\lambda s \,\, dx + \int_\lambda ^1 t \,\, dx = \lambda s + (1-\lambda)t$$ and $$\int^1_0 f(g(x)) dx = \int_0^\lambda f(s) \,\, dx + \int_\lambda ^1 f(t) \,\, dx = \lambda f(s) + (1-\lambda)f(t).$$ Clearly such $g$ is bounded and measurable so the assumed inequality gives $$f(\lambda s + (1-\lambda)t) \le \lambda f(s) + (1-\lambda)f(t).$$ Since $s,t \in \mathbb R, \lambda \in [0,1]$ were arbitrary, this shows that $f$ is convex.