# Prove that $f$ is a convex function if $f(x) \leq \int \limits_0^1 f(x + \alpha \cos(2 \pi y))dy $

Tags: integration, functions, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a continuous $\mathbb{R}$-valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x) \leq \int \limits_0^1 f(x + \alpha \cos(2 \pi y))dy~~~~\forall x,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$$
Prove that $f$ is a convex function.

My attempt:

1. $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi k}{n} \right) =0$, so $f(x) =
   f \left(\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \left(x +\alpha \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi k}{n} \right)\right)\frac{1}{n} \right) $
2. $\int \limits_0^1 f(x + \alpha \cos(2 \pi y))dy = \sum \limits_{k=1}^n
   \frac{1}{n} f\left(x + \alpha \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi k}{n} \right) \right) + o(1)$
3. And now the inequality in the condition is similar to Jensen's inequality,
   but it is not a definition of a convex function.

Also, $\int \limits_0^1 \cos(2 \pi y) dy = 0$, so my question is a variation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996916/suppose-that-f-on-0-1-satisfies-f-int-01-g-dx-leq-int-01-fgx-dx).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely attract downvotes or even be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body (as clarifications don't belong in the comments).

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis, I'm sorry I thought my attempts didn't matter

Comment: They always do! It shows that you actually tried to come up with the solution yourself and not just copy and pasted the problem here expecting others to solve it for you. This happens very frequently with homework problems.

Comment: Not sure if useful, but the condition is reminiscent of the mean value inequality for subharmonic functions (on the real line, these functions are exactly the convex functions).

Comment: Yes that's an interesting point, but I think this problem can be solved by simpler methods.

Comment: In the answer you have linked, set $g(y) = x + \alpha\cos(2\pi y)$, with $x$ and $\alpha$ fixed. Then we have that $f(\int_0^1g(y)dy) \leq \int_0^1f(g(y))dy$, so $f$ is convex.

Comment: @V.S.e.H.: That answer assumes that $f(\int_0^1 g(x) dx) \leq \int_0^1 f(g(x)) dx$ for *all* bounded and measurable functions $g$, not just for $g(y) = x + \alpha\cos(2\pi y)$.

Comment: @MartinR Good point, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that
$$
 L(x) = \int_0^1 L(x+\alpha \cos(2\pi t)) \, dt
$$
holds for all *linear* functions $L$.

Now fix $a < b$ and let $L$ be the linear function satisfying $L(a)=f(a)$ and $L(b) = f(b)$. We have to show that
$f(x) \le L(x)$ for $a \le x \le b$.

Assume on the contrary that
$$
 M = \max \{ f(x) - L(x) \mid a \le x \le b \} > 0 \, .
$$
The idea is to show that if the maximum is attained at some point in $(a, b)$ then it is in fact attained in a neighborhood of that point. That will lead to partition of $[a, b]$ into disjoint, non-empty, and relative open subsets, which is not possible.

So let $c \in (a, b)$  be a point where the maximum is attained. Choose $\alpha > 0$ such that $[c-\alpha, c+\alpha] \subset (a, b)$. Then
$$
 M = f(c) - L(c) \le \int_0^1 (f-L)(c + \alpha \cos(2 \pi t) \, dt 
\le \int_0^1 M \, dt = M \, .
$$
Since $f-L$ is continuous, this implies that $f(x)-L(x) = M$ for all $x \in  [c-\alpha, c+\alpha]$.

It follows that the sets
$$
 A = \{ x \in [a, b] \mid f(x) - L(x) < M \} \\
 B = \{ x \in [a, b] \mid f(x) - L(x) = M \} 
$$
are

- both relative open in $[a, b]$,
- both non-empty: $a, b \in A$ and $c \in B$,
- disjoint,
- and their union is the interval $[a, b]$.

This is a contradiction to the fact that intervals are *connected.*

So $M > 0$ is not possible, and therefore $f(x) \le L(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

Comment: You mean that for all $\alpha$ such that $[c - \alpha, c + \alpha] \subset [a, b]$ we can get $f(x) - L(x) = M$ for all $x \in [c - \alpha, c + \alpha]$. And therefore $B$ is open. Am I right?

Comment: @math-fighter: Yes, because it implies that every point $c \in B$ has an open neighborhood $(c - \alpha, c + \alpha) \subset B$.

Comment: Thank you for your great solution!